# getComputedStyle(...) does NOT return pixel values in jsdom in Svelte

Tags: testing, jestjs, svelte, sveltekit, getcomputedstyle

I am using jest and testing-library/svelte to write tests in SvelteKit. I have a simple text-component and want to test, if the line-height of the text is big enough depending on the font-size (because of accessibility reasons). For this, I want to use the window.getComputedStyle(...) method. However, if I am using it in a test, the font-size is NOT returned in pixel, but the unit I used in the actual css.

Text.svelte:

```
<div class="text">
    <slot></slot>
</div>

<style>
    .text {
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 2.4em;
    }
</style>
```

Text.spec.ts

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
 
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render } from "@testing-library/svelte";
import Text from "./Text.svelte";
 
describe("Text component", () => {

    test("text must have a minimum line-height of 1.5x the font-size", () => {
        const { container } = render(Text);
        const textDiv = container.querySelector(".text");
        const fontSize = window.getComputedStyle(textDiv).getPropertyValue('font-size')
        const lineHeight = window.getComputedStyle(textDiv).getPropertyValue('line-height')

        console.log("fontSize:", fontSize)      // Output --> font-size: 1.2em
        console.log("lineHeight:", lineHeight)  // Output --> line-height: 2.4em
    });
 });
```

jest.config.cjs

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
      "^.+\\.svelte$": [
        "svelte-jester",
        { preprocess: "./svelte.config.js" },
      ],
      "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "ts-jest",
    },
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "svelte"],
    moduleNameMapper: {
      "^\\$lib(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib$1",
      "^\\$app(.*)$": [
        "<rootDir>/.svelte-kit/dev/runtime/app$1",
        "<rootDir>/.svelte-kit/build/runtime/app$1",
      ],
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts"],
    collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.{ts,tsx,svelte,js,jsx}"],
  };
```

jest-setup.ts

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

Just in case, here are the relevant dependencies from my package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "svelte": "^3.46.6",
    "svelte-check": "^2.2.6",
    "svelte-jester": "^2.3.2",
    "svelte-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.1",
    "svelte2tsx": "^0.5.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

So how can I get the font-size and line-height in pixels. Is this even possible in a jest-test? I'd appreciate every answer, ideas or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

JSDOM doesn't have fully implemented CSS. Specifically, the cascade part of CSS is not implemented (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2690). Inheritance is only partially implemented (display and visibility) (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2160).

Thus, to test computed styles, you should look for e2e tests.